# Cómo cambio un mapa de Leaflet con un click en Angular 13?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, leaflet, click

Quiero mostrar un mapa de Leaflet y que este cambie (su url específicamente) con el click de un botón.

Lo he intentado con la función changeUrl pero sale el error *Property 'changeUrl' does not exist on type 'Map Component'*
Y si pongo la función fuera de  ngAfterViewInit() me salta *ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Map container not found.*

Mi **map.component.html**:

```
<div>
        <div>
            <button id="1" (click)="changeUrl(1)">Day 1</button>
            <button id="2" (click)="changeUrl(2)">Day 2</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="map1"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Mi **map.component.ts**:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-map',
 templateUrl: './map.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 constructor() { }
 
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   var url1 = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
   var url2 = 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

   const map1 = new Map('map1').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
   tileLayer(url1, {attribution: 'Day one'}).addTo(map1);

   function changeUrl(output: any) {
     if(output == 1) {
       L.tileLayer(url1, {attribution: 'Day one'}).addTo(map1);
     }
     if(output == 2) {
       L.tileLayer(url2, {attribution: 'Day two'}).addTo(map1);
     }
   }

 }
}
```

He probado a cambiar directamente el id="map1" del div con funciones, esconder y mostrar varios divs, crearlos y destruirlos con *nfIf, usar setUrl de la api de Leaflet (dice que no existe en el tipo 'Map')... pero todo me da errores, supongo porque no lo estoy haciendo bien. Soy nuevo en programación y no consigo encontrarle una solución. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Hey! This is a Spanish forum. Please, translate your question to the Spanish, or ask it in Stack Overflow. If you don't do it, the question will probably be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`map1` pasa a ser una propiedad de la clase para que esté disponible para todos los métodos. `changeUrl` pasa a ser un método de la clase, y las url se mueven al método `changeUrl`.

```
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  
  map1: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map1 = new Map('map1').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    tileLayer(url1, { attribution: 'Day one' }).addTo(this.map1);
  }

  changeUrl(output: any) {
    const url1 = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const url2 = 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

    if (output == 1) {
      L.tileLayer(url1, { attribution: 'Day one' }).addTo(this.map1);
    }
    if (output == 2) {
      L.tileLayer(url2, { attribution: 'Day two' }).addTo(this.map1);
    }
  }
}
```